# How can Discrete Fourier Transform yield negative frequencies?

Tags: fourier-transform

(*This question is about an answer on Mathematica, but is about purely mathematical concepts, so I found it was more appropriate to ask it here rather than on Mathematica.*)

I'm trying to challenge myself into drawing any shape using **Discrete Fourier's Transform** and **epicycles** ([like this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVuU2YCwHjw)).

[This answer on Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171755/how-can-i-draw-a-homer-with-epicycloids) does exactly what I want, however there's something I can't get my head to work with. Here's what I achieved and understood so far :

- To map an arbitrary shape into a series of epicycles, I'm using a Discrete Fourier Transform. This transformation will give an array of complex numbers that I will map to an array of epicycles (Each complex number is an epicycle).
- As per [the mathematical definition of Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition), each of these epicycleswill have a frequency that ranges from 0 up to the number of samples I have in input (e.g. 100 input samples in DFT will yield 100 complex numbers, hence 100 epicycles, each having a frequency from 0 to 100).
- The frequency of an item is mapped to the orbit of the epicycle. A frequency of 0 means 0 rotation per unit of time. A frequency of 20 means 20 rotations per unit of time.
- Since those frequencies have a range [0;inf] that means all the epicycles spin either clockwise or anti-clockwise (the DFT doesn't yield negative indexes).

With all that in mind, **I cannot understand why the animation in the aformentioned question shows some epicycles spinning clockwise, and some other spinning anticlockwise**.

This doesn't make sense to me since DFT yields only complex numbers that map to frequencies ranging from 0 to +inf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterclockwise rotation $\omega$ rad is equivalent to a *clockwise* rotation of $2\pi - \omega$. This effect is similar to seeing the spokes of a bicycle wheel run backward as $\omega\mod 2\pi$ approaches $2\pi$.

Comment: Okay I was so thrown off by the smoothness of the animation that I forgot that a frequency larger than 2*pi could create such an effect. Thanks for the quick response !